# New Row Created In DataGridView When AutoComplete Dropdown Clicked On

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, autocomplete

I've implemented AutoComplete like this in my DataGridView on several of my textbox columns.

```
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
List<string> values = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridRoadway.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
{
   if (columnName == "Road Name")
      {
         values.Add(dataGridRoadway.Rows[i].Cells["Road Name"].Value.ToString());
      }
}

source.AddRange(values.ToArray());

//Set the appropriate properties on the textbox control 
TextBox dgvEditBox = e.Control as TextBox;
if (dgvEditBox != null)
{
   dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
   dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
   dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

When an item from my AutoComplete source is selected using the mouse, the current row is incorrectly set to a new row (selecting an item from AutoComplete using the arrows and tab doesn't trigger a new row). This in turn, fires the RowValidating event and runs my validation logic on the entire row before the user is actually done entering data from that row.

I would guess that DataGridView detects my mouse click on the AutoComplete dropdown and associates it with clicking on a new row. Of course, this is not the behavior I need. Is there a way around this? Is there a way to detect an AutoComplete selection and then override the new row being created?